# Trying to understand why child entity state does not change when parent entity state is changed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

This is how my model looks like:

A `Branch` belongs to an `Organisation`. An `Organisation` belongs to a `User`:

```
[Table("branch")]
public class Branch
{
    public long BranchId { get; set; }

    public string BranchName { get; set; }

    public long OrganisationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrganisationId")]
    public Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
}

[Table("organisation")]
public class Organisation
{
    public long OrganisationId { get; set; }

    public string OrganisationName { get; set; }

    public long UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}

[Table("userprofileview")] // <-- UserProfile is representing a view 
public class UserProfile
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`UserProfile` entity is representing a view and is not insertable (because it has a left join).

I want to add a new `Branch` to an existing `Organisation` (which belongs to an existing `User`), the following code gives me an error:

```
public void AddOrUpdateBranchAsAdminUser(Branch branch)
{
    if (branch.BranchId > 0)
    {
        // code to update branch
    }
    else
    {
        _context.Branch.Add(branch);
        _context.Entry(branch.Organisation).State = EntityState.Unchanged; // <-- Don't update Organisation 
        /*
         * uncommenting this line will fix the problem
         * _context.Entry(branch.Organisation.UserProfile).State = EntityState.Unchanged;  
         */
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This is the error that I get:

> The target table userprofileview of the INSERT is not insertable-into

If I uncomment the line that sets the state of `UserProfile` then it works fine... Is anyone able to explain this behavior? I would have expected that changing `Organisation` state (parent entity) should change the state of `UserProfile` too.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to Entity Framework caching.

The message you get

> The target table userprofileview of the INSERT is not insertable-into

You get this because, as you said,

> UserProfile entity is representing a view and is not insertable (because it has a left join).

This seems to make sense so far...

Once you remove the line

```
_context.Entry(branch.Organisation.UserProfile).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

You are marking the cached record as unchanged. This means that when you SaveChanges(), Entity Framework will NOT attempt to push any updates to that record to the database. I can't answer HOW UserProfile is getting "touched" but you have the attribute

```
[ForeignKey("UserId")]
```

On the Organization. I have a feeling, since you are changing the Organization object, that Entity Framework is trying to "touch" all the child objects. It seems this is somehow generating an "Insert" on user profile. Your fix is to set the object to Unchanged so that entity framework never attempts to push any modifications to this table.

Edit: I might be able to explain this behavior if 1) You generate a new Branch. 2) Associate an organisation to the Branch that is not in the EF cache. 3) Associated organisation has a User Profile that is not in the EF cache. I think if you generated a branch in this situation, EF will automatically attempt to serialize your related objects and insert them into the database.

You could break this pattern if you changed your classes similar to

```
[Table("branch")]
public class Branch
{
    public long BranchId { get; set; }

    public string BranchName { get; set; }

    public long OrganisationId { get; set; }
}
public class BranchComposite
{
    public Branch Branch { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OrganisationId")]
    public Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... what I meant is why this line:  `_context.Entry(branch.Organisation).State = EntityState.Unchanged;` does not do the trick, because `UserProfile` belongs to the `Organisation`

Comment: Set it to null right before you save and let me know if that works.

Comment: Or better yet remove it from the context so it's not tracked anymore